How to estimate the expected bin size "N" from "q" unique values among "p" draws, with replacement?

I have a set/bin/bucket containing an unknown N number of balls.
Each elements ("balls") are assumed to have the same probability of being picked up.
I wish to estimate N by drawing (with replacement) s times from it, and then counting the number of unique (distinct) balls u.

Example : if I draw s=1000 times (with replacement), and I get u=500 distinct (unique) elements, I intuitively know that N>=500, and N is probably less than 1,000,000,000 (I would have gotten more distinct values otherwise).
It seems that the probability distribution of N could be known, and an expected mean value can be inferred.
Note : I would like to avoid Bayes formula, since I do not want to assume any prior for N
Edit : it seems that the question was also asked here: Estimating population size from the frequency of sampled duplicates and uniques but no satisfying answer were given (2 solutions for E[U]+Bayes Theorem, and 1 numerical solution using a R package)

Could you be more specific about what you mean by "unsatisfying"?  After all, Henry's answer in the linked post gives the distribution explicitly.  Do you need help obtaining its expectation?

As I said, I dont want to assume any prior on (=). Henry's answer is a Bayesian answer, not a Frequentist answer.

Subject to mild "regularity" assumptions, all admissible frequentist methods are equivalent to a Bayes method.  So, as Henry writes, pick a suitable prior.  Some details lurk in that recommendation.  For instance, you needn't select a prior based on any particular subjective "belief" about a random parameter.  You can select it to achieve other objectives, such as minimizing an expected loss.
